# Why to open the window shields on a plane?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, aircraft

Why does the captain order the passengers to open the window shields on an air plane when taking off or when landing?

I've asked the flight attendents many times. The answer has always been the most annoying one:

"This is the rule."

But why????

Comment: I think flight attendants may be a bit reluctant to talk about it being preparation for an emergency because they might be overheard by someone who is scared of flying.